# php - Unable to exec this command

Tags: php, linux, awk

This command will return the upload rate of a server in MB/s:

```
awk '{if(l1){print ($10-l2)/1024/1024} else{l1=$2; l2=$10;}}' <(grep eth0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep eth0 /proc/net/dev)
```

It works very well via Linux terminal/SSH, but when I use `system()`, `exec()`, or `shell_exec()`, it's just showing me:

```
# php -q geturate.php 
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

My php source code:

```
<?php
$command = 'awk \'{if(l1){print ($10-l2)/1024/1024} else{l1=$2; l2=$10;}}\' <(grep eth0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep eth0 /proc/net/dev)';
$result = system($command);
echo $result;
?>
```

How do I run that command via php?

*php version on server : 5.6*

Comment: Have you tried `$result = system(escapeshellcmd($command));` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) which should ensure that the command isn't mis-interpreted.

Comment: just getting this error :
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in geturate.php on line 2`

Answer (score 0):

Little bit change system instead of exec use in php

```
<?php
$command = 'awk \'{if(l1){print ($10-l2)/1024/1024} else{l1=$2; l2=$10;}}\' 
<(grep eth0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep eth0 /proc/net/dev)';
$result = exec($command);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: just try to run this : exec('awk -v OFS=, \'/hello/i {$1=$1;print}\' test.txt > newtest.txt');